# Unable to find an entry point named 'GetAsncKeyState' in DLL 'user32'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to catch all keystokes  and I am getting and "Unable to find an entry point named 'GetAsncKeyState' in DLL 'user32'" error at 
  result = GetAsncKeyState(i) 
here is the code

```
Private Declare Function GetAsncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Integer) As Integer
Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim key As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 90
        result = 0
        result = GetAsncKeyState(i)
        If result = -3276 Then
            key = Chr(i)
            If i = 13 Then key = vbNewLine
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: I am using framework 3.5 , visualstudio 2010

Comment: Curious how you got the name wrong, do explain how this happened.

Comment: @HansPassant is correct, the name is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error you described is because the function name is **[GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**, not **GetAsncKeyState**.

Also in **.NET** you should consider to use the [`DllImport`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute instead of `Declare` statement (which is an obsolete *VB6-stylish* methodology) to [provide more control over how platform invoke functions are called](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172wfck9.aspx).

Here is below the `GetAsyncKeyState` declaration [that I use](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/Elektro.Interop/Win32/NativeMethods/NativeMethods_Devices.vb), with XML documentation included:

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, 
''' and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to <see cref="GetAsyncKeyState"/>.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <remarks>
''' <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx"/>
''' </remarks>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="vKey">
''' The virtual-key code.
''' <para></para>
''' You can use left- and right-distinguishing constants to specify certain keys.
''' <para></para>
''' See Virtual-Key Codes: 
''' <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx"/>
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <returns>
''' If the function succeeds, 
''' the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to <see cref="GetAsyncKeyState"/>, 
''' and whether the key is currently up or down.
''' <para></para>
''' If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, 
''' the key was pressed after the previous call to <see cref="GetAsyncKeyState"/>.
''' <para></para>
''' However, you should not rely on this last behavior.
''' <para></para>
''' <para></para>
''' The return value is zero for the following cases: 
''' <para></para>
''' The current desktop is not the active desktop.
''' <para></para>
''' The foreground thread belongs to another process and the desktop does not allow the hook or the journal record.
''' </returns>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys
) As Short
End Function
```

Note: You can change the `vKey` parameter to `Integer` datatype if you preffer.

Comment: I believe you meant: _"You can change the `vKey` parameter to the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration if you prefer"_. :)

Comment: Whoops, forgot to upvote your nice answer.

Comment: @Visual Vincent In technicisms of course yes, in context of the provided answer not. Thanks for comment.